# iOS: Not getting emoji in Push Notification - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, push-notification, emoji

I have implemented emojis in chat in my application, which is working fine in my app. But when I am getting same message through push notification it shows the unicode instead of the emoji. Can someone please help me out?

Here is the screenshot:

[Notification showing Unicode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phy9j.jpg)

[Message showing emojis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiflw.jpg)

Below is my code I have used to convert emoji and displaying it again in my Message Page:

```
- (NSString *)convertSmiley:(NSString *)type :(NSString *)text {
    NSString *emojiValue = @"";
    if ([type isEqualToString:@"encode"]) {
        NSData *data = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
        emojiValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
    else {
        NSData *data2 = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        emojiValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data2 encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    }
    return emojiValue;
}
```

Comment: From where you are sending notifications? backend or frontend?

Comment: From Backend...actually the notification comes when one user sends a message to another user..the notification comes with the message that the user has sent. You can check the screenshot (attached) to get more idea

Comment: Please ask your backend team to send decoded remote notification. They will appear fine in default iOS notification center.

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal Okay. Can you give me some reference (if you know any) for decoding the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of our project we use the encoding-decoding of message, because smiley sent from iOS was not appearing correct in Android and vice-versa, smiley from Android was not appearing correct on iOS.

So we had the approach, to encode the message and sent it to server. They were saving the data in encoded form and sending same encoded data to other mobile end, where it was decoded.

> **But for remote notification,**
>
> **Notification push from server is shown in default iOS popup on notification center handled by device itself. Our decoding happens only inside of the application and hence your message will appear in encoded form on device.**

[image]

**To solve this:**

We asked backend team to send remote push message by decoding at their end first.

**We used following code to encode-decode methods in Swift:**

```
// Encode strings in UTF-8 format
func encode(_ s: String) -> String {
    let variable = s.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)!
    return variable
}

// Decode strings in UTF-8 format
func decode(_ s: String) -> String? {
    let val = s.replace(target: "+", withString: "%20") // + appears in string while encoded from android
    let decodedString = val.removingPercentEncoding!
    return decodedString
}
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the answer, Ankit. I'll check with the backend person.

Comment: Your answer worked for me. Now I am getting Emojis in notification. Thanks for the help. :)

But the issue stuck in Database now, I am sending the message (that is percentEncoded as shown in your above code) “Hii%F0%9F%98%8A”. But it is getting stored in DB as “Hii????????”. Can you suggest what is wrong?.

Comment: I think they are saving the message after decoding. Just ask them to save encoded format. And when notification will be sent they will fetch from DB, decode and will send to mobile app in payload.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ankit. Your answer worked!. Cheers!! :)

Comment: @GautamShrivastav, Welcome :)